# NiFi DeleteMongo with particular _id

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

So my flow is a querydatabase table to get _id from sailfish -> convertAvroToJson -> SplitJson -> EvaluateJsonPath -> DeleteMongo.

My goal is to delete out any records in MongoDB that have an _id which is generated by my Query from QueryDatabaseTable.

I'm confused on how to flow the _id's from my query into the delete for my delete mongo. I'd assume I'd want something like {"_id" : "$._id"} with the $._id which becomes a variable via the EvaluateJsonPath.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From the DeleteMongo docs

> This processor deletes from Mongo using a user-provided query that is provided in the body of a flowfile. It must be a valid JSON document. The user has the option of deleting a single document or all documents that match the criteria. That behavior can be configured using the related configuration property. In addition, the processor can be configured to regard a failure to delete any documents as an error event, which would send the flowfile with the query to the failure relationship.

So your FlowFile going in to DeleteMongo needs to look something like (needs to be a valid query for your Mongo)

```
{ "id" : "100" }
```

Using QueryDatabaseTableRecord with a query that returns the 'id' field e.g. `SELECT id FROM table;` with a JSONRecordSetWriter (infer schema should be fine).  DeleteMongo reads FlowFile content, so you can set `Max Rows Per Flow File` to 1 such that each result creates its own FlowFile (no need to split).

Then pipe straight in to a DeleteMongo.

DeleteMongo docs https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-mongodb-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.mongodb.DeleteMongo/

QueryDatabaseTableRecord docs https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryDatabaseTableRecord/index.html